# Why does changing my time step result in zeros when solving a system of ODEs?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I have correctly solved a system of ODEs to calculate a car’s trajectory from a given steering input:

`A` is a matrix describing the vehicle parameters; `b` is a vector based on vehicle parameters; `u` is the steering input; and `V` is the velocity. The parameters `A`, `b` and `V` are not time dependent. The steering input (radians) is a time-dependent step input as shown in the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# model parameters
m = 1500 #mass
I = 2500 #moment inertia
lf = 1.1
lr = 1.6
Cf = 55000 #tire stiffness
Cr = 60000
V = 27.77    
A = np.array([[-2*(Cf+Cr)/(m*V), (2*(Cr*lr-Cf*lf)/(m*V**2))-1,0,0,0],[2*(Cr*lr-Cf*lf)/I, -2*((Cf*lf**2)+(Cr*lr**2))/(I*V),0,0,0]])
b = np.array([(2*Cf)/(m*V),(2*Cf*lf)/I])


def func(x,t):

    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]
    x4 = x[3]
    x5 = x[4]
    
    if t>1 and t<1.5:  # steering inputs
        u = .2
    elif t>3.5 and t<4:
        u=-.2
    elif t>8 and t<8.5:
        u = -.2
    elif t>10.5 and t<11:
        u = .2
    else:
        u=0
   
    dx1dt = np.dot(A[0,:],x) +b[0]*u 
    dx2dt = np.dot(A[1,:],x) + b[1]*u
    dx3dt = V*np.cos(x5+x1)
    dx4dt = V*np.sin(x5+x1)
    dx5dt = x2
    return [dx1dt, dx2dt,dx3dt,dx4dt,dx5dt]

x0 =[0,0,0,0,0] # initial conditions
t = np.arange(0,20,.005) #timestep 0 to 20 seconds at .005sec interval
x = odeint(func,x0,t)

x1 = x[:,0]
x2 = x[:,1]
x3 = x[:,2]
x4 = x[:,3]
x5 = x[:,4]

plt.plot(x3,x4) # x3 is x position, x4 is y position
plt.xlim([0,600])
plt.ylim([0,40])
```

Now, depending on the timestep, I get totally different results:

- For 0.005 and 0.08, I get a correct solution.
- For 0.03, I get a solution that is only zero.
- For 0.08, I get an incorrect non-zero solution.

Why would changing the timestep result in a zeros for the other variables?
How can one know which timestep values provide a correct solution without knowing the correct solution beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe is probably due to the following:

- `u` suddenly changes on very small time scales compared to your integration time.
- The `t` argument of `odeint` is not prescribing mandatory integration steps, but rather points at which the solution is evaluated. `odeint` may decide to take coarser steps than given in `t` and then interpolate the result at the points given in `t`. However, `t` does affect the guess of step sizes and thus the steps actually taken. (I am not completely sure about this since I cannot find it documented, but it’s a common behaviour for integrators and perfectly matches your observations.)

As a result, `odeint` may completely step over the intervals where `u` is different (steering inputs) and thus your car is computed to drive straight instead of taking a turn. For example in such a case, your function `func` simply never gets evaluated for any time between 1 and 1.5 and thus `odeint` cannot possibly know that it changes its behaviour in that interval.

To avoid this, set the parameter `hmax` which governs the maximum step size such that at least one step has to be within a steering interval:

```
x = odeint(func,x0,t,hmax=0.49)
```

The adaptive integrator will then take care to further scale down the steps accordingly.